# Symlink to PHP script under a different user/home directory: "No input file specified"

Tags: php, bash, apache, symlink, fastcgi

I'm running virtualmin with apache2 on debian wheezy and standard PHP 5.3 and fastcgi

I have a website that calls a symlink pointing to a php file in another user's home directory

so /home/user1/public_html/adserving/ is symlinked to /home/user2/public_html/

The problem is that if I access user2's php file directly, it works, but if I access it through symlink it just spits out "No input file specified" (i guess fastcgi does not find the file's path?)

This is my php5.fcgi for user2:

```
#!/bin/bash
PHPRC=$PWD/../etc/php5
export PHPRC
umask 022
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=99999
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
SCRIPT_FILENAME=$PATH_TRANSLATED
export SCRIPT_FILENAME
exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

This is my apache conf for that virtualserver:
<

```
VirtualHost XXXXXXXXXXX:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1012" "#1012" 
ServerName adserve.com
ServerAlias www.adserve.com
ServerAlias webmail.adserve.com
ServerAlias admin.adserve.com
DocumentRoot /home/adserve/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/adserve.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/adserve.com_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/adserve/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/adserve/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/adserve/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/adserve/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
<Directory /home/adserve/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.adserve.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://adserve.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.adserve.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://adserve.com:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
php_admin_value engine Off
IPCCommTimeout 31
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
</VirtualHost>
```

(the domain adserve.com is just a placeholder)

Any advice on how to solve the fcgi path resolution problem (if that is indeed the problem) ?

Thanks

Comment: Is `PHPRC=$PWD/../etc/php5` not the problem? Isn't that wrong when accessed through the symlink? (I don't do php so I could be entirely off about this.)

Comment: did you check your permissions? cause you're trying to reach user1 files with user2 and suexec won't allow it.

Comment: I have tried disabling fastcgi and making php run as mod_php with apache's user...but I still get exactly the same behavior

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to solve the problem by relaxing the permissions on the whole traversal path to the file I was trying to symlink to. It needs full read and execute access on the whole path to work as intended

Thanks to all that helped